# Glide Android Image library is replacing semicolon with %3B in my URL

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using Glide Library to load images dynamically in my Android App.
Glide automatically replaces ';' with '%3B' and I get Failed to load resource error.

The URL works fine with Picasso library, but the loading is kind of buggy with recyclerview, so I switched to Glide.

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an URI instead of a String.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://etc.com/im;png");
Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

Comment: yup. not working. use this as example: http://api.met.no/weatherapi/weathericon/1.1/?symbol=9;content_type=image/png